# Can't figure out how to upgrade my python version from 3.4 to 3.7 in my virtual environment

Tags: macos, terminal, dependencies, homebrew, python-3.7

In my virtual environment I am running on python 3.4.3 but need to upgrade to python 3.7 .

[Show version and brew install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcBwj.png)

I have tried brew install python3 and changing the link and homebrew tells me python 3.7 is installed. When I do python --version it states python 3.4.3.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best method is to leave Python 3.4.3 as is and install python 3.7. Then after installing 3.7 create a new virtual environment for python 3.7. To run 3.7 you just activate that environment.